# Sharepoint 2007 Search Tool

Tags: 2007, search, seo

I'm trying to find a **search tool** for SharePoint 2007 aside form Google search engine, would you know some?

I hope you could help me, it will just be an interim while we are still planning for our migration to SharePoint 2013.

Maxine.

Comment: What do you mean by "Search Tool"? SharePoint 2007 has a built in search engine. No need for Google.

Comment: Search tool for publishing site, I saw Coveo but other than that I cannot find other 3rd party tool that is still compatible to 2007.

Comment: I don't understand, why not just use SharePoint? Any third party can crawl SharePoint as a web site.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I'm sorry I forgot to tell you that I'm just a new SharePoint Dev, I'm also quite not familiar on how to use the built in search engine in publishing site. I saw some videos on using it but in a team site. The Intranet site that I'm currently handling is using Google however it will be expired soon, that is why i'm looking for another third party tool aside from Coveo. If there's any.

Comment: I don't bother with third party tools since SharePoint Search does a good job in 2007 (and better in 2010 and best in 2013). You should learn about SharePoint and see what it does out of the box before looking further afield. Are there specific business requirements that you need to meet? Any plans to Upgrade?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott yes there is a plan to upgrade, however would you know how many items can crawl on SharePoint 2013 and how could I use it on a publishing site? We'll be considering first the built in search before we decided on what third party tool to use, if ever the built in search will not be able to handle the number of items we need to be crawled.

Comment: You can have 10M items per index partition. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Search You can create a search site collection for you publishing site. Very Easy.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I just distilled our comments into an answer, can you give me a vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "Search Tool" for SharePoint 2007, but there is a built-in Search Engine that has gotten better with each successive version of SharePoint (2010 and 2013). For example, performance and scale have improved significantly.